# How to show vertical rows into horizontal columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a sales table that looks like below:

[image]

I would like to display sales data month wise in the below format:

[image]

Can anyone help me with SQL for this?

Comment: You're asking for pivoting. There are a lot of related questions that show how to do it either for fixed or dynamic row values

Comment: Those 2 duplicates should be all the "help" you need.